# Perl Tk HList: Opposite of -browsecmd?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I currently have a HList set up so -browsecmd calls a subroutine when ever an entry is selected. I would now like to have a subroutine run when the user *un*selects an entry.

I have tried to google for this, but I have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `-browsecmd`, too. The callback is executed whenever a user browses the HList. This also happens when unselecting an entry.

Using `my @selected_items = $hlist->info('selection');` you can then access the currently selected items.

There is a complete example here (last example): http://www.perltk.de/tk_widgets/wtk_hlist.html